# Open + Save File window buggy in several applications (resizing left side also changes right side, moving window moves application, etc.)

Tags: firefox, libreoffice, emacs, okular

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, and several applications (Emacs, Firefox, Okular, Libre Office, OpenSCAD) all have buggy popup windows for opening and saving files. For example, when saving a file in Firefox using ctrl+s, the popup window where one specifies file name and location exhibits the following behaviour:

1. Adjusting the top edge of the window also moves the bottom edge and vice versa (dragging the top side up/down moves the bottom side down/up)
2. Adjusting the left edge of the window also moves the right edge and vice versa (dragging the left side left/right moves the right side right/left)
3. Moving the popup window also moves the application window (most annoyingly: it de-maximizes the application window if it was maximized)

Is this a problem with the applications or is this a problem with my system?

Comment: I was able to replicate the "bugs" with Firefox on my Ubuntu 20.04. I suspect this is due to the [GTK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTK) tool kit used to create the GUI for Firefox and other apps you mention. This is probably a "feature" of GTK. In any case, bugs are off-topic here. See [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) for more.

Comment: @user68186 not a bug, but a "feature" indeed.

Comment: @vanadium great answer! So, is it a gnome feature or is it specific to GTK as I assumed?

Comment: @user68186 specific to Gnome Shell!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a problem with your system. This is how it works by default. Modal dialogs (e.g. a file dialog) are attached to their parent window and cannot be moved. The parent window is darkened. Parent window and the dialog are moved together. This gives a visual hint that you need to cope first with the dialog before being able to continue working.

Fortunately, this behaviour can be turned off with the following command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter attach-modal-dialogs false
```

The setting is also exposed in Gnome Tweaks (not installed by default) on the Windows tab ("Attach Modal Dialogs").

[image]